# Date comparrison issues

Tags: php

Using my very limited understanding of the time and strtotime functions, I've written a little code which is intended to check if the current date is later or or earlier than another.

Let's assume that $_editDateString var contains the string "second tuesday of this month" - the intended functionality is for $_finalEditDate to end up containing the date (in d/m/y format) for this month's second tuesday **if that date is in the past** and otherwise to contain the date 4 weeks prior to it - thus $_finalEditDate should only ever contain dates that are earlier than or equal to today's date.

Unfortunately I just can't get the damn thing to stop producing dates in the future.

Here's the code, I'd be greatful if someone less awful at php could tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
if (time() >= date("d/m/y",strtotime($_editDateString))){
$_finalEditDate = date("l d/m/y",strtotime("$_editDateString"));}
else{
$_finalEditDate = date("l d/m/y",strtotime("$_editDateString - 4 weeks"));}
```

Comment: `time()` returns an integer, `date()` returns a string, `strtotime()` returns an integer. You really do not need `date()` here.

Comment: Thumb rule: don't convert to string to do maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing dates in PHP, there are two approaches:

1. Convert both dates to Unix timestamps. ¹
2. Use real [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) objects, which can be compared natively.

The first looks like this:

```
// NOTE that both timestamps are expected to be in UTC
$timestamp1 = strtotime("2015/12/03 04:33");
$timestamp2 = strtotime("2015/12/01 05:33");

if ($timestamp1 < $timestamp2) {
    // …
}
```

The second one would look like this:

```
$tz1 = new DateTimezone("America/New_York");
$tz2 = new DateTimezone("Europe/Berlin");
$date1 = new DateTime("2015/12/03 06:00", $tz1);
$date2 = new DateTime("2015/12/03 09:00", $tz2);

// Note that $date1 is later, because the timezone adds an offset

if ($date1 < $date2) {
    // …
}
```

The decision which approach to use depends on your application. If you’re only processing a few dates on the fly, in the same timezone, and ignoring things like DST, use the first approach. If you have a more complex application and need to take timezones and DST into account, real DateTime objects may be a more solid choice.

The decision which approach to use depends on your use case. If you’re comparing dates generated by your system, be sure that they are in UTC, and you’re fine with using simple timestamps. As soon as you’re using user input dates or dates that refer to dates outside your system (e.g. calendar entries or public transportation schedules), use real `DateTime` objects with the correct timezone.

¹ Unix timestamps are normally assumed to be in UTC. Of course, when you get a date like `2015/12/03 04:33` through user input and convert it with `strtotime`, you will also get a timestamp. But implicitely, this timestamp will refer to a local date. And when such dates refer to different time zones and you try to compare them, you’ll get into trouble.

Comment: Unix timestamps are absolute (i.e. time zone independent) so the expression "in UTC" does not apply. The rest of the explanation is flawless.

Comment: Of course. I just wanted to point out that you can’t just convert a local date string to a timestamp and start comparing. I’ll clarify my answer.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly... A Unix timestamp cannot have a time zone or be assumed to be UTC or anything similar. Time zones only apply to **local** times. Now it's timestamp 1447069325 and you don't need time zone information at all.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: I know what you mean. This is clear in theory, but still many developers simply convert their user input dates to timestamps, and then e.g. compare it to whatever `time()` gives them. So, I just want to make sure that user input must be converted to UTC before comparing it to timestamps (or use `DateTime` from the start) – simply look at the other answer to this question to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Compare value returned from `time()` with value returned from `strtotime($_editDateString)`, and format that date with `date()` function.

```
if (time() >= strtotime($_editDateString)){
    $_finalEditDate = date('l d/m/y',strtotime($_editDateString));
} else {
    $_finalEditDate = date('l d/m/y',strtotime($_editDateString) + strtotime('-4 weeks'));
}
```